# How to replace only quotes inside a specific tag

Tags: regex, vim, vi

How to replace only some quotes and retain all the content, Please see the below example

```
<type>"sample"<type> 
<content>R.A.H.M.A.N. sample text."</content>
```

to

```
<type>"sample"<type>
<content>R.A.H.M.A.N. sample text.</content>
```

Replace the quote inside `content` tag only, is it possible?

Comment: If you want to replace all quotes use: `%s/\"/ /g`

Comment: @wp78de talks about a command, you have to type it command-mode, so the keystrokes are: `:%s/\"/ /g` <Enter>. You just seems to be very new Vimmer, this is why I explain it. BTW the command means: `%`: in the whole file; `%s/XXX/YYY/`: replace XXX by YYY; `g`: all match in the line (not just the first one).

Comment: Why you add the regex tag to the question and don't ask about a regex? And if you know you are looking for a regex, you should find out how to do a regex in vim. And if you know what a regex is you should be able to do the simplest case of a regex. So do we get the question wrong or are you lazy? Please consider updating your question with a specific question!

Answer (score 0):

If all the `<content>` tags are on a line by themselves, you can use the `:g` command:

```
:g=<content>.*</content>=s="==g
```

This will replace all quotes on all lines that contain an open and close `<content>` tag. (This does not necessarily mean those quotes are inside the `<content>` tag.)

See [:help global](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:global).

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s!<content>\zs\_.\{-}\ze</content>!\=substitute(submatch(0), '"', '', 'g')!g
```

The idea is:

- Run a substitution command on all lines and for all hits in a single line: `:%s!...!...!g`
- Search for `<content>`, followed by 0 or more characters (as few as possible), followed by `</content>`: `_.{-}
- ... but set the start of the match just after `<content>` and the end of the match just before `</content>`, respectively: `<content>\zs...\ze</content>`
- This means we're not substituting the `<content>` and `</content>` parts themselves, just the contents.
- Replace it by the result of running an expression: `\=`
- The expression is `substitute(submatch(0), '"', '', 'g')`:

  - Take the text matched so far: `submatch(0)`
  - Search for all `"` and replace them by nothing: `substitute(..., '"', '', 'g')`